# Text formatting as like web text editor in android

Tags: android, web-services, textview

I am getting data from web service and displaying in the text view.
In web side i have a text editor to enter the data for a field. Now i want to display the data as such the format given in the text editor say line spaces, line breaks, font styles, font sizes etc., in the andriod textview. 
The web data is stored in server using php. 
Retrieving the data using json parsing.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to display it in a TextView and not a WebView?

Comment: I just want the formatted text given from the admin side

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

```
your_textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your_html_code_from_json"));
```

fromHtml() allow you to write html content in textview with html tags effects.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: for that you have to create webservice.